# What is the purpose of these 2 different javascript declarations?

Tags: javascript, closures

I think I have this figured out, but am hoping to cleary have this explained -- what precisely is the difference between these two javascript snippets?

```
;Person1 = (function() {
  var FirstName = 'Hello';
  var LastName = 'World';
  this.sayHello = function() {
    alert(FirstName + ' ' + LastName);
  };
});

;Person2 = (function() {
  var FirstName = 'Hello';
  var LastName = 'World';
  this.sayHello = function() {
    alert(FirstName + ' ' + LastName);
  };
})();
```

One is being executed with the (); at the end, the other is not. They both perform as expected when I do new Person1().sayHello() or new Person2().sayHello(); -- is it what they leave behind? From what I understand, the latter is a closure that is executed AS IT IS READ by the browser, but I haven't yet fully grasped the implications of that. Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: I mistakenly left out the return keyword in the Person2 closure. I did not fix this, however, because the answers were very helpful in describing the implications of doing this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main motivation behind self-invoking functions is to avoid polluting the global namespace. You may be interested in checking out the following resources for further reading:

- [A Week in JavaScript Patterns: Self-invocation](http://www.lovemikeg.com/blog/2008/08/17/a-week-in-javascript-patterns-self-invocation/)
- [Stack Overflow: JavaScript idiom: create a function only to invoke it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698548/javascript-idiom-create-a-function-only-to-invoke-it)

Comment: Thank you sir. Succinct answer to what I wanted to know: it's all about scope.

Answer (score 0):

`Person1` is a fairly standard type of object constructor function, meant to be called with `new`.  `new Person1()` creates a new object, and creates a `sayHello` method on that object.

`Person2` is being executed immediately, which is causing some problems! As `Person2` is being evaluated, the function is called (in a global context).  Inside the execution of that function, `this` will be the `window` object.  The executed function doesn't return anything, so `Person2` ends up being undefined:

```
>>> Person2 = (function() { var FirstName = 'Hello' // ...}; })(); 
>>> console.log(window.sayHello, Person2);
function() undefined
```

A `new Person2()` is resulting in a `TypeError` "Person2 is not a constructor" for me.  If you change this up a little, you can make the `Person2` closure return an object with your function:

```
;Person2 = (function() {
  var FirstName = 'Hello';
  var LastName = 'World';
  return {
    sayHello: function() {
      alert(FirstName + ' ' + LastName);
    }
  };
})();

Person2.sayHello();
```

Or make it return a function (so you can `new Person2()`):

```
;Person2 = (function() {
  var FirstName = 'Hello';
  var LastName = 'World';
  return function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
      alert(FirstName + ' ' + LastName);
    };
  };
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thoughtful explanation -- I mistakenly left off my return in the creation of the Person2 closure. I'm glad I did, though, because your response reminded me of the `global` implications of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

the first one defines a function inline and `Person1` holds a reference to it.

the second one amounts to no action taken. you're defining a function inline and executing it immediately. since the function doesn't return anything, `Person2` is undefined.

neither example behaves as you describe, so perhaps you've made an error typing up your example?

Comment: `Person2` may be undefined, but it also sets `this.sayHello` which will create `sayHello` on the `window` object.

Comment: My bad -- you're right, there is a typo in my person3. I've edited it now. Thanks.