# What is benefit of using (function(){...})() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

I noticed in JQuery that the following code structure is used

`(function(){var l=this,g,y=l.jQuery,p=l.$,...})()`

Which seems to create a function, and call it.

What is the benefit of taking this approach versus having the contents of the function inline?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript

Comment: This one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631187/javascript-scope-and-closure

The problem is that the findability of these questions/answers is not good. If all I know is "[javascript] (function()", then search does not do a good job finding anything useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It creates a closure to prevent conflicts with other parts of code. See this:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Particularly handy if you have some other library that uses the `$()` method and you have to retain the ability to use that with jQuery also. Then you can create a closure such as this:

```
(function($) {
    // $() is available here
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

It creates a scope for variables, in particular defining `$` for example to bind to `jQuery`, no matter what other libraries overwrite it. Think of it as an anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 1):

With self invoking anonymous function you create a local scope, it's very efficient and it directly calls itself.

You can read about it [here](http://www.lovemikeg.com/blog/2008/08/17/a-week-in-javascript-patterns-self-invocation/)

Answer (score 0):

It's just like:

```
var foo = function(){var l=this,g,y=l.jQuery,p=l.$,...};
foo();
```

But more simple and do not need a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

It allows to have local variables and operations inside of the function, instead of having to transform them to global ones.